# "Не удалось обработать пакет" - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, apk

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На всех версиях Android работает, кроме 11 андроида.
Проблема очень странная, долгое время пытался и пытаюсь решить.
provider тоже есть.
Перепробовал разные способы, ничего не меняется. В манифесте есть разрешения:

`android.permission.INTERNET`
`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
`android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
`android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`

Версия апи: compileSdk 31, targetSdkVersion 28, targetSdk 27, compileSdkVersion 31

да, кстати, если зайти в какой-нибудь проводник, установить приложение оттуда - все устанавливается.

[image: код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: provider в манифесте]

[image: ошибка]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: помогите, я не могу найти причину уже неделю